# Unable to fetch values from local XML file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am new to JavaScript. I have a XML file from which I am trying to fetch values but the variable shows null.

XML file (data.xml)

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<color>f0f8ff</color>
```

I am tring to fetch value of the `<color>` element. The XML and `.js` files both reside in the same folder.

js code-

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET" ,
 url: "data.xml" ,
 dataType: "xml" ,
 success: function(xml) {

 if single item
 var value= $(xml).find('color').text();  
}       
});
```

The Ajax call is not happening.
Can anyone help me with this? Or else is there any other way to fetch value from xml?

Comment: Are you opening the page you run this from on a server or by opening the file through `File/Open`?

Comment: I am directly opening the html file without using server.

Comment: in chrome I bet - check the browser developer tools console for errors (regarding CORS probably)

Comment: Error - jquery.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///C:/example/data.xml: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: That is a browser security feature. Implement a localhost server to open page on. There are numerous ways to set one up

Comment: I want to implement without any server

Comment: You don't need a remote server but setting up a localhost one can be done very easily and is a prerequisite to doing ajax. There are browser extensions you can use also to prevent CORS but since it is so easy to run a local server I've never used them

Comment: Is there anyway to implement without setting up localhost?

Comment: @RakeshRaigar Look for the javascript api to read files from filesystem.